# How does the print function know what to print or ignore in a string reversal recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

Here is the code for reversing a string. I understand how this recursive function works (see attached photo). [screenshot of the breakdown of code, with the part in question encircled in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiELB.png)

```
def rev(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev(s[-1]) + rev(s[:-1])
```

The output of `print(rev("cabin"))` is "nibac".

However, the part where I am confused is how does the print function know which returned value to print? Why are the values inside the green circle not being printed? See the green circle in sreenshot.

What I expected to happen is to reverse a string fed into the rev function. What I don't understand is how come only the values of `rev[-1]` are being printed and not the values of `rev[:-1]`?

Comment: There is no `print` in your code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I assume you have something like `print(rev('cabin'))`.  That's only going to print the result of the final `return`.  All those intermediate returns, when `rev` calls itself, don't get printed because you haven't printed them.

Comment: @Julien I updated my post to hsow that I called the print function.

Comment: then as Tim said...

Comment: What do you mean by "which return value to print"? Your function, any function returns only one value. It may have multiple return statements but during runtime only one is reachable.

Comment: @TimRoberts Still confused. How does python know which are the final `return`?

Comment: Perhaps you should write down step by step what your function does for small input, say `abc`.

Comment: The recursive calls to rev() are all fully resolved before the final value is passed to print.

Comment: Hi @freakish. English is not my first language so I am having a hard time articulating my thoughts. What I meant to ask is, how come the `return` of the `rev` function is composed of concatenated `s[-1]` after each run of the recursive call? Why are the values of `s[:-1]` not being concatenated in the final return of the `rev` function?

Comment: Each call to `rev` stands alone.  It just like calling another function (like `len`) and using the result it returns.  In this case, it just happens to be calling the SAME function, but it just calls that function and uses the value it returns.  You could (for example) have 9 different copies of that function, where `rev` calls `rev1`, and `rev1` calls `rev2`, and `rev2` calls `rev3`, etc.  That works exactly the same, but makes the nesting more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some help to visualize how the recursive function works.

TLDR is: only the return of the first time you call `rev()` is returned to the `print` function, all the other returns end up in the parent `rev()` that called because `len(s) > 1:`

```py
def rev(s, depth=0):
    if len(s) == 1:
        print("│ " * depth + "├─ rev(\"" + s + "\")")
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        first_char = s[0]
        rest_of_string = s[1:]
        print("│ " * depth + "├─ rev(\"" + s + "\")")
        print("│ " * (depth + 1) + "├─ rev(\"" + first_char + "\") + rev(\"" + rest_of_string + "\")")
        result = rev(rest_of_string, depth + 2) + rev(first_char, depth + 2)
        print("│ " * depth + "└─ \"" + result + "\"")
        return result

print(rev("cabin"))
```

Output

```
print(rev("cabin"))
├─ rev("cabin")
│ ├─ rev("c") + rev("abin")
│ │ ├─ rev("abin")
│ │ │ ├─ rev("a") + rev("bin")
│ │ │ │ ├─ rev("bin")
│ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("b") + rev("in")
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("in")
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("i") + rev("n")
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("n")
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("i")
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─ "ni"
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─ rev("b")
│ │ │ │ └─ "nib"
│ │ │ │ ├─ rev("a")
│ │ └─ "niba"
│ │ ├─ rev("c")
└─ "nibac"
nibac
```

Comment: Also pythontutor [link](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display) is a good way to visualize such processes without writing additional code.

Comment: Awesome tool, is there any way to have it advance on it's own? like one step every second or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way.  Here is the same code, implemented without recursion.  You would NEVER really write the code this way, but maybe seeing it written out will help you to understand the recursive version.

```
def rev7(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev8(s[-1]) + rev8(s[:-1])

def rev6(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev7(s[-1]) + rev7(s[:-1])

def rev5(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev6(s[-1]) + rev6(s[:-1])

def rev4(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev5(s[-1]) + rev5(s[:-1])

def rev3(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev4(s[-1]) + rev4(s[:-1])

def rev2(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev3(s[-1]) + rev3(s[:-1])

def rev1(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev2(s[-1]) + rev2(s[:-1])

def rev(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    if len(s) > 1:
        return rev1(s[-1]) + rev1(s[:-1])

print(rev('cabin'))
```

As you can see, the code for all 8 versions here is identical.  The execution path is identical to the recursive version.  It will execute the same number of instructions and go through the same operations.  The only difference is that THIS version requires way more typing.